# How many different types of YouTube Vanced are there?

Tags: youtube

I have many YouTube accounts, and signing in and out is inconvenient. That's why I use different YouTube Vanced for different YouTube accounts. At present, I have three YouTube Vanced: version pink, blue, and this one of which I don't know the name.

[image]

I need another version of YouTube Vanced other than these 3 for my other YouTube account.

I can't use apps like Dual Apps to make a copy of YouTube Vanced because then signing in won't work. I have also downloaded many versions from the internet but in the end, I found them all similar to my previously installed versions of YouTube Vanced.

How many different types of YouTube Vanced are there?

Answer (score 1):

There are 4 YouTube Vanced versions: Blue, Pink, Dark, and Black.

You already have YouTube Vanced Blue and Pink. I'm not sure if you have Black or Dark, but one of them should work for you.

[This XDA thread](https://www.xda-developers.com/youtube-vanced-apk/) contains download links as well.

Some Alternative Apps

1. NewPipe [Link](https://newpipe.schabi.org/)
2. YouTube Go [Link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.youtube.mango)
3. OgYouTube [Link](https://ogyoutubeapk-download.com/ogyoutube-apk-download/)

Comment: Each time I try to install any dark or black version from the site you given, it gives the message that the app is already installed, are you sure YouTube vanced black and dark different apps?

Comment: I think both have same package name for sure if shows this message

Comment: You can give a try to app Called NewPipe which also works great as YouTube with download option and pip mode

Comment: Unable to login in newpipe and Ogyoutube, in Ogyoutube I tried to install micromg but it can't install, is that because I already have vanced micromg?

Comment: Can't understand @Kirandeep Maan what you commented

Comment: The microg provided in OgYouTube should be installed for the sign-in btw u already installed microg of yt vacant if both installed at same time both will work